# link_to one page but controller from another in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, syntax, controller, web-crawler, link-to

I've seen some similar questions on stack but I don't think this is a duplicate as each answer I've gottent has been specific to one underlying problem.

Ill keep it simple. I'd like to know how to click a link, have it take the user to one page but execute a def from another. This is in a rails application of a web crawler and Its something I thought would be quite simple but turned nasty on me.

At the moment I have:

```
<td><%= link_to 'Crawl!', crawl_path  :controller => :crawl, :action => :crawl  %>
```

This takes the user to the crawler's index page after its done running. 
What I would like to do is redirect them to a different page. Namely jobs_path which shows a list of the crawlers sites and status (this is working fine, I just want to included it for relevance). If I try it like this:

```
<td><%= link_to 'Crawl!', jobs_path,  :controller => :crawl, :action => :crawl  %>
```

The user is directed to the jobs page but the crawler script never ran and thus the jobs list was never update. For the record, each job is just a url and the depth that it lies at.

Is this just a syntactical error or am I miles off the mark?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: On a side note. How do I delete from a record like this. @jobs.delete?

Comment: In your controller `destroy` action you'd do `@jobs = Job.find(params[:id]);@jobs.destroy`.  You can have that on two lines and get rid of the `;`.  You'll need an appropriate `link_to` helper to direct to the destroy method, i.e. `<%= link_to "Delete", job_path(job), :confirm => "Are you sure?", :method=>:delete %>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What have you set your `redirect_to` in `crawl#crawl` as?  Perhaps set it to redirect to `jobs_path` upon completion?

Comment: I would add the proper route as well: `crawl_path` so you'd have: `link_to "Crawl!", crawl_path`

Comment: @you2guys Thanks! I just changed it there. Im still getting my head around syntax and good practice in ruby.    @Mike  I dont have any redirects in the crawl#crawl. I don't even know how to be honest. Is your suggestion that I link to the crawl page and redirect from there?

Comment: <meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=http://127.0.0.1:8080/jobs">   simple enough. just put this in the crawlers show page. Worked like a charm.

Comment: @overtone best [you read this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-redirect_to) - that would be the rails way of going about it.  You might also want to consider doing `redirect_to jobs_path and return`.

Comment: @Mike I have something like that now for database comparison but it doesnt work because job.all is returning empty and I have no idea why.